# Using serialization to send objects over sockets instead of strings

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, serialization

I'm making a game in C# that uses sockets to transfer data between players including three floats for the position and one for rotation. Currently I'm doing this with strings encoded to binary and I know that this is very inefficient and could cause issues at 32 updates per second with 5 players on a server especially due to having to convert from float to string and back and splitting strings. I think serialisation could be good due to (I assume) its space efficiency and speed. I'm still unsure about a few things though:

1. Is it more space efficient?
2. Is it faster to serialise than convert to a string?
3. How would I separate objects? (I used "<EOF>" to know where each update ended with strings)
4. Is serialisation a good idea?
5. Are there any other recommended alternatives

Comment: I don't think there will much of a performance difference. There are other things you should rather focus on: 1. minimizing network traffic/traffic size. 2. Don't initialize new buffers with every receive. 3. Avoid converting between different objects too much.

Comment: What kind of serialization? You're doing serialization already, you're just doing your own kind instead of the kind you're thinking of

Comment: Binary serialisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be using the binary serializer because as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) it is a massive security vulnerability

Comment: What you are not going to do, is something that belongs in the question, not a self-answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a big topic. You can use a well known serialisation library , communications framework or build your own. Have a look at [Message pack](https://msgpack.org), [Protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) [gRPC](https://grpc.io) and so on for libraries and frameworks. If you want to build it all yourself I'd recommend using fixed frames. Have a look at [Stephen Cleary's blog entry about Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) as well as the new [IO Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) too especially if you want to build a terminator separated protocol yourself.